# How to automate beeline commands to various hive queries?

Tags: shell, hive, beeline

I have to automate a couple activities in the beeline same as we can do things in HIVE CLI. Below are the running sample shell script for HIVE automation task::

```
echo "using new_db HIVE database..!!"
hive -e "use new_db;"

echo "truncating the staging table test..."
hive -e "TRUNCATE TABLE new_db.test;"

echo "Loading the data into the staging table test"
hive -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/<path>/IDI.txt' INTO TABLE new_db.test;"

echo "Appending the data into history table hist_test.."
hive -e "insert into table new_db.test select *, '$unix_time' from new_db.test;"
```

I would like to do a similar thing for beeline. I am a starter for beeline. So I came up with something as below.

```
#! /bin/bash

timestamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S:%N)
unix_time=$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S)

echo "Login to BeeLine..!!"

#beeline << EOF

beeline -u jdbc:hive2://server:port,server:port,server:port/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/server@hello.COM<< EOF -n <username> -p <password>

echo "using new_db HIVE database..!!"
beeline -e "use new_db;"

echo "truncating the staging table test..."
beeline -e "TRUNCATE TABLE new_db.test;"

echo "Loading the data into the staging table test"
beeline -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/<path>/IDI.txt' INTO TABLE new_db.test;"

echo "Appending the data into history table hist_test.."
beeline -e "insert into table new_db.test select *, '$unix_time' from new_db.test;"

EOF
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++

## new syntax

```
#! /bin/bash

export BEELINE_PREFIX="jdbc:hive2://server:port,server:port,server:port/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/server@hello.COM"

export FILE_PATH="path_toFile/staging_hive_tables.hql"
beeline -u $BEELINE_PREFIX -f $FILE_PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this.

```
export BEELINE_PREFIX='beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://bigdataserver-xxxxxx.net:10000/;principal=hive/bigdataplatform-xxxxx.net@XYZ.NET;ssl=true" --silent=true --verbose=false --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 -e  ' # set hive.cli.print.header=false;
export PARTY="xxxxx"
export load_date="20181003"

###  Get the table count  ### 
########################################################################
export BEELINE_COMMAND="select count(*) from ${DMAR_HIVE_TABLE} where load='${PARTY}' and load_date=${yyymmdd} ; ";

echo "Hive command=$BEELINE_COMMAND"
${BEELINE_PREFIX}"${BEELINE_COMMAND}" | read table_count
check_count=$?
echo "Check count = $check_count"
echo "Table count = $table_count"
```

**EDIT1:**

The double quote is getting missed.. wrap the BEELINE PREFIX with single quotes
try this

```
#! /bin/bash

export BEELINE_PREFIX='"jdbc:hive2://server:port,server:port,server:port/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zookeeper;zookeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;principal=hive/server@hello.COM"'
```

**EDIT2:**

I ran these in the command prompt

```
> export BEELINE_PREFIX='"jdbc:hive2://xxxx:10000/;principal=hive/yyyyy@zzzzz;ssl=true" --silent=true --verbose=false --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 '
> cat /tmp/hive1.ql
select current_date;
>  echo "beeline -u ${BEELINE_PREFIX} -f /tmp/hive1.ql " | sh -x
+ beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://xxxx:10000/;principal=hive/yyyyy@zzzzz;ssl=true' --silent=true --verbose=false --showHeader=false --outputformat=csv2 -f /tmp/hive1.ql
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release

2018-10-12
>
```

Note that you need to echo commands and pass it to a shell ( sh )

echo "beeline -u ${BEELINE_PREFIX} -f /tmp/hive1.ql " | sh -x

Comment: To test, I have created a .hql file, which contains the simple hive query to create hive table. At the beginning of the file I have mentioned the JDBC connection URL follwed by -n <uid> -p <pawd>, but when I am executing "beeline -f test.hql", I am getting " No current connection". I have manually logged in to the beeline with the URL and password, it worked. Any suggestion?

Comment: the snippet I provided will work for a functional-id where authentication is taken care using kerberos. You need to run the snippet as bash shell script under the functional id and not as beeline sql.. Hope, it helped you, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but now I ma getting weird error "Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'beeline' '-' 'u' (state=42000,code=40000)". I have updated my main post with teh new syntax

Comment: check my EDIT1.

Comment: you haven't included "beeline -u" in the BEELINE_PREFIX, so you need to pass that to shell in the second statement. check my EDIT2 which worked in my machine

Comment: thank you, I fixed that problem. Issue resolves. I have another issue, posting new query for that

Comment: I tried up voting, but I do not have enough reputation. Sorry